# Source Maps with Sprockets 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, sprockets

I have a Rails 5.0.4 app and I'm trying to get js source maps so

1. I have upgraded `sprockets` to `4.0.0-beta5` (latest)
2. I have upgraded `sprockets-rails` to `3.2.1` (latest).
3. I have created `app/assets/config/manifest.js` as follows

   > ```
   > //= link application.js
   > //= link application.css
   > ```

However, when I run `bin/rails assets:precompile` no `.map` file is created.

Am I missing anything here?

I'm using the `uglifier` compressor

```
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
```

UPDATE

After few more research, I have updated my manifest as follows

> ```
> //= link application.js
> //= link application.js.map
> //= link application.css
> ```

This generates a `.map` file but also a bunch of files that weren't created before.

```
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/application.js-2c9ef72a80f5f0c6011537311d91fd1196ae2bef80ed0b82b00c6eb87ee82af9.map
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/application.js-2c9ef72a80f5f0c6011537311d91fd1196ae2bef80ed0b82b00c6eb87ee82af9.map.gz
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery.source-430f36f9b5f21aae8cc9dca6a81c4d3d84da5175eaedcf2fdc2c226302cb3575.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery_ujs.source-784a997f6726036b1993eb2217c9cb558e1cbb801c6da88105588c56f13b466a.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/core.source-62aad85719b507a830934d0fbe64de7816cd70c818eca1b06587484e94d65ec7.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/widget.source-417dab6d8413c3e391f31430d6158e9e2211045c27756faad88479c980048ae3.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/accordion.source-66807da00144fb00ff8ce5e181be52e74badb11213966ce258c89c000318340e.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/position.source-ba98b4672be13a5780636b01c3daf137d14194857ca89cc8916ca8833534d54f.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/menu.source-203fcd6601bca475f3af5e18f1456a2b6f73dfb73a0122c6782ce0b9eb530b21.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/autocomplete.source-3989c376efd2db3eac613502e79e9728f1798ebe6b7972d4dc2b13949127cb37.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/button.source-227dc04f5202bbc454b55bc29fd327feaba1bc35517bab5dcde5020590eccec9.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/datepicker.source-1f11dcdb22842d981e8e1af2a2e950ed936bb3a687df7712d3a7f9b4f7c8efad.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/mouse.source-8aea6124865ee5bb79161dcebac8ca767fd1c9a65fe385f765036f95ba8a9f15.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/draggable.source-8e00381a5b1a9280d1923fe9176e978cfd75179f969ed12276bb5834d8f5ef0e.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/resizable.source-de7c87bc6d811e1d625611495b1bdcd6decdbe4a39cef77d11701829f13a267b.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/dialog.source-ae7be51a416c21041eab27126160360283cfbef61fa323fa08f5eb8b775d9223.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/droppable.source-826e8dea9801e835ec92a884327e92849bb0c5dfe1bbcb5cb284f135fdeb3124.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/effect.source-8db1c4cb4869865486337383ad3388cd2e8a2f9dca5d4b5efc5d88d126690319.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/effect-blind.source-f11c9927fe07bd2e5a2722cb1bf4ba04832f2dea398a66b138bd0833056aab37.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/effect-bounce.source-6c8eea42de6760931b676ff88fe5e34bcc368821e174309dcb1d50b56e6d5a66.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/effect-clip.source-d965ee17f7081704307e25f6923fb7ab54bb8c2c6a567d7e2a5234150a4db7d9.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/effect-drop.source-403c2419a8592d1f8a079ee87dddabf79929e0075c72db1b634ac6c1cbc05f8e.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/effect-explode.source-0f8d2da0c4f281703692ad937a0b75dd802e81a9c98f98b7a190f384173b01fc.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/effect-fade.source-461344d8873890497042865f7b54a580309015faa683853346629dddd8ce98e4.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/effect-fold.source-55e61e90915325fc938e55ddeb1ac429a92d267fd67170c4d2acd0fbeb78925d.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/effect-highlight.source-5919339b87e2c4f7b0ab257142f86437cc70d64540a2488a2ec91c526b0ecc6e.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/effect-size.source-d8fed86501d05ba3c4122a4da365823eea4f002f33df9e7e050d52498008d5ab.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/effect-scale.source-2ae4287a7828eb94c3816acf2c540eda762db5b21e211051d3a91528ec70f185.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/effect-puff.source-74e0a9be48670c114bcdaceb3f59127b289d0b803420ca7e615636a6aa952f87.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/effect-pulsate.source-2bdd8fe4f42163b02241271f78cd5342c51c4d8518fbe1f9396b5356f2cda66f.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/effect-shake.source-3de440615bf624285099e557e3816c75c910a8d28e4fc4becc81dc6319d0187c.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/effect-slide.source-65492cb7aaf4877459d9b14cc0f405c2c05ff7975cbe25ed51f0d77cf3d0166a.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/effect-transfer.source-2a82ed5e844e4608632a7af5db2ed2769e5808b8a73119881e6952acaa6b0f12.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/progressbar.source-23e568a1f0b304cab9f7436dc14ae0cb98dfb2a0b0be55d844a1c2afbb7b4ccd.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/selectable.source-3cac427596eb57fd65cc221f100b1fed97208ed5e90b63cc34193779a4d5239c.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/selectmenu.source-4b3dbcc750e1d4abf19fe8c55bf3ffd5d30a3b24353b9b38024a123d16608888.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/slider.source-d3e34873f1f61dc6d48c6dfc8f6c40cec03cd57aebc97c7d0557a84a548b93d5.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/sortable.source-17e6ca11fd2db332538edde0c4c682ddd94a0e9ecba9e6382ec3b41f363f5a42.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/spinner.source-f692c0893790e36df32afa54142d352df08c50f040a569b557551314641e0fb9.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/tabs.source-e243c9e4636923e05819aa98fbceea7583ff23cf4e7b360c20caf3878ba1b10b.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui/tooltip.source-9e84eed1867034b12a15b0a724a61775427b3081a3ec68485ff2d2cb0f749861.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui.source-9783639d92b424aa71a5b6323d7d6270d90e9cd0d7d72c249cb0debf413e61bb.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.source-12e2a259f64b5c81f764e5b92342bba87dc79851e96d935739f84d6f4f12c9f3.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/lib/abstract-chosen.source-417d20dc3ad76e699eea6415cd41805dc78dc0956819f2b8fa9bd40bc0489f04.coffee
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/lib/select-parser.source-5b527c7cca7f0cf7a898008da6bc85dd84f778879b2fb02cefde8c12d277b045.coffee
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/chosen.jquery.source-92895979d5681aff42c01b681d7b6655642f1fa9cf936b57e7f7677ba5b5085b.coffee
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/chosen-jquery.source-eccf0f52e3890ef5d4d04a7662e5fb5a64a11df1727f33eb7741ba2e49509ed9.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/i18n.source-b2f11db80d9fd9e9c90640f9df297165fbd03c5ea628ca35d4057287d7bfa970.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/i18n/translations.source-24affd4dd922a168c3b6e4910e44bcbcbcd9b4db1db954b835065f7cef4540dd.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/loading_buttons.source-250525fd4ee12eb2c4624323ec1e0066406d9c3594f2efb7aa6de2f33296352c.coffee
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/lib.source-fd9ebc2909df4cf04f90be8813fae881e1836c582eabe435482ca79870b6568a.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/bootstrap/affix.source-1ee8ac8eff7b2c225d85963ee6160f0071297a3fdaf1532688c4fe01cfc0fb94.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/bootstrap/alert.source-bf5bf7c66a7596b466425b03510276de2013f8da3d4eab474b544c323b40c9c9.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/bootstrap/button.source-318791b8d45a0840fb365758254c88018813dc074a15816bbc34371e85b16f95.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/bootstrap/carousel.source-8267c3df279fd9d3c5697fae952443782aa70ea97bfb18b9a4af9b8b1ae934a7.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/bootstrap/collapse.source-7febc2b3ac8b8e30b18df2cb8cbfcef590a2788526a40ec9b039701096354a04.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/bootstrap/dropdown.source-92d4c20f5350f2ba58e5dd6dea20685850c0ed453eeaf4be0174ec300a19e7c1.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/bootstrap/modal.source-d52795b36f7aca99c78a0b84b17f425c8878dd44b87620b629521f388fa8b0a8.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/bootstrap/scrollspy.source-1271feec9ed30f0f41dfacd74a9203178ea9b97ae881e0e67f8f5b4584158657.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/bootstrap/tab.source-43e16be52d7c5353c317273b82e5c58d5ab30c85a567deaa0b52dfdc54deec9b.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/bootstrap/transition.source-4c4992c0cea541a09ca27f2fff93f9b0cbb4ad28065af1ffccf711f53b67f976.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/bootstrap/tooltip.source-3bc9620928f72c4e1181b208f0d8f63be31ae35a03e0de7c967c14b4d9360db7.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/bootstrap/popover.source-9eafe4728dfc7e529f79efd40c66905b3c6eeffec39e7411c84aac54c5ed4cd1.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/bootstrap-sprockets.source-262274a43e32b99ef023040786584b4db38cf893f3c28aaa23574a6567504c83.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/bootstrap-material-design/material.source-23e3086555a6b17d7b1c123389651cdbcdd365f70b8da34ad5810a71c7280390.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/bootstrap-material-design/ripples.source-7de6843440e0251bbeab3b392cb3abc270f97c68d0fb4b291215e90d83674cbd.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/bootstrap-material-design.source-03d81c89120e795d19e60cddf6645dd9a5d0240ae22608ea166ea69387231aca.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/vendor.source-d0fd5abf73d983a08f5befaed86684696ff73585f4810abcd11fd53d2d9ccf78.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/audit-trail.source-181a3fc5ec6311762c9b17c4c50b0ee78eb068cdfab3741a2f3507ebbbefed3b.coffee
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/batch_histories.source-50d2da588e7b39e98dce5a0df91d4a7a8893442532b6aa0ad848e7eb0d09b322.coffee
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/bootstrap.source-8057220619b3b7b56b846fd64b9d2c203d22dd2a1204f59af3f6db7d68bb5008.coffee
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/chosen_init.source-5fef3227af8a59f3f6c5104aeb9733a236af77048c322d545ee519d2370b4377.coffee
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/datetimepicker_init.source-9a5cb1407e2f553519caef93dc7bd29aec742ec71d9ae6e980a69ac6649fda15.coffee
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/sensors.source-6462eb67e0d55cf105a602eca12b3cb9178629c6cd5900b172b1504f4f0e6aaf.coffee
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/toggle-password.source-f7fb634377c9013cf1ccee3f4ca6102131aac023c0968bc3178c0c70f7582d10.coffee
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/toggle_visibility.source-0e159adfa64243d79dc8607cb592b2296c169d63ce8e016c570f644869f7ed17.coffee
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/transits_searches.source-4d01dcf6b435cc749be54dce99def6c1fb8ef23f9c181cee32ee52df5468eee7.coffee
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/ui.datepicker-en.source-640e26ff3258c83ac80eaa83834d83fca7440651cedf0d760a6f6d2d45b6ddb2.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/ui.datepicker-it.source-be738eaa0d5657c9861204ed0e31044007d36d8b2fa73f75435d2b6b0630ea3a.js
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/users.source-8a372c734d1862db16214049afe537c4b7370267d887d3526a2e7eb9e88ba62a.coffee
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/zones.source-e72579ef412bd2cd545e6c45b071dfcc5ea6b69a49f73d624c8213bd3b5b0f92.coffee
I, Writing /appy/public/assets/application.source-b2e607455e883bd704a7ffedd03ad332ce989d8257711449ed8ab26ec5b2c02c.js
```

Thanks.